# Pandas select values from each hour for each ID

Tags: python, pandas, hour

I have a dataframe in which I have some IDs, and for each ID I have some values and timestamps (around one value each 5 minutes for 5 to 7 days in a row). I would like to select, for each hour and for each ID, the mean, median and variance of the values in that hour and store them in different columns like in the following result:

```
hour   mean    var   median     ID
0       2       4      4        1234 
1       4       5      3        1234
...
23      2       2      3        1234
```

My columns are:

```
ID                       int64
Value                  float64
Date            datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

My timestamps are in the following type:

```
%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f
```

How do I create the final dataframe for each ID? Thank you very much

Edit:

With the following line I created a column correctly with the hours:

```
df['hour'] = df.Date.dt.hour
```

Now the problem is that I have a very long column with the hours, the same, and if I use the resample like this:

```
df = df.set_index('Date').resample('60T').mean().reset_index()
```

automatically it erases the value columns and overwrites with the mean values. I would like to keep that columns, so that i can create different columns for mean, variance and median, based on the values in the Value columns. How can I do that part?

Comment: I believe you are looking for [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

Comment: yes, but with resample I'm getting a giant space between the timestamps of different IDs. If I'll use the .dropna() will be the same?

Comment: can the mean for each hour cross days? or is it an average for that hour that day in that ID?

Comment: it is an average for that hour that day in that ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Extract the hour from the Date column
h = df['Date'].dt.hour.rename('Hour')

# Group by ID and Hour
df.groupby(['ID', h]).agg({
    'Value': ['mean', 'var', 'median']
})
```

You can replace the `h` series by `pd.Grouper`. By default `pd.Grouper` groups the index. You can set the `key` parameter so that it targets another column:

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper('1H', key='Date'), 'ID').agg({
    'Value': ['mean', 'var', 'median']
})
```

Comment: I successfully created the hour and the columns hour. But now I have a list of rows with the same hour. How can I create a single cell of a specific hour containing mean, median and var of all the values in that hour?

Comment: Then remove ID from the groupby call

Comment: by doing this I'm getting an error `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'` with the following code: `df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq = "1H"), "ID"]) \
      .agg({"Mean": np.mean})`

Comment: I'm getting: `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'key'` Also, I tried to create different dataframes and then merging them all, but when I perform the following code: 'df1 = pd.DataFrame() \ df1 = df.set_index('Date').resample('60T').mean().reset_index()' to store the result in the newly created df1, the df is the same and doesn't even perform mean

Comment: this is the result I get after your code: everything is ok, but need to reindex stuff but I cannot: https://imgur.com/a/nfImzUm